# Marcado incorrecto de nodos en TreeView

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy intentando montar un `TreeView` con `CheckNodes` y tengo un problema a la hora de seleccionar/deseleccionar los nodos haciendo *click* en la raíz. En este [clip](https://vimeo.com/368259705?ref=em-share) entenderéis que es lo que me ocurre exactamente.

Normalmente funciona de forma correcta pero a veces se atasca y no se marcan/desmarcan correctamente. Creo que es un conflicto con el evento de selección pero no lo se con seguridad.

Estos son los métodos que he utilizado para seleccionar/deseleccionar los nodos:

```
private void Treeview_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
        if (e.Node.Checked)
        {
            CheckAll(e.Node.Nodes);
        }
        if (e.Node.Checked == false)
        {
            Uncheckall(e.Node.Nodes);
        }
}

public void Uncheckall(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = false;
        foreach (TreeNode node1 in node.Nodes)
        {
            node1.Checked = false;
            foreach (TreeNode node2 in node1.Nodes)
            {
                node2.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
}


public void CheckAll(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = true;
        foreach (TreeNode node1 in node.Nodes)
        {
            node1.Checked = true;
            foreach (TreeNode node2 in node1.Nodes)
            {
                node2.Checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y esto es lo que he intentado para arreglar el tema del conflicto de la selección (obviamente sin éxito):

```
private void TreeView_Select(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeView.SelectedNode = null;
}
```

¿Alguna idea sobre como arreglar este fallito? Gracias.

Comment: No puedo ver el vídeo ¿No puedes describir el problema? En un repaso rápido tus funciones `Check` y `Uncheck` pueden ser recursivas y sólo una: `public void Set(bool state, TreeNodeCollection nodes) { foreach (TreeNode node in nodes) { node.Checked = state; Set(state, node.Nodes); } }`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que quieres hacer está desarrollado en la documentación del evento que has capturado: [`TreeView.AfterCheck`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck?view=netframework-4.8), ahí se propone una solución recursiva, tal y como he propuesto yo también en los comentarios de tu pregunta.

Te propongo cambiar las funciones `Checkall` y `Uncheckall` por una sola función:

```
public void Set(bool state, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
{
    foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
    {
        node.Checked = state;
        Set(state, node.Nodes);
    }
}
```

Tu captura de evento (que es casi idéntico al ejemplo de la documentación) podría redactarse así:

```
private void Treeview_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
        Set(e.Node.Checked, e.Node.Nodes);
}
```

Comment: Hola PaperBirdMaster gracias por tu respuesta. Creo que he arreglado el tema del clip, disculpas por ello. Sin duda el código que me propones está bastante mejor del que yo tengo, pero de todos modos sigo teniendo el mismo problema, que consiste en un pequeño conflicto cuando se selecciona en lugar de hacer click. Es algo confuso de explicar y por eso he colocado el vídeo. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Un saludo.

Comment: Puedes ver este comportamiento extraño exactamente en los segundos 7, 10 y 15 del vídeo. Un saludo.